# How can I list visits on my site so they don't recur?

Tags: javascript, api

**I wanted to list all the real accesses to my web page but if I already accessed it from that device then it won't count**
*I can use the hosting for example the cpanel that gives me this data but I need it to print on my screen new visits  *

> below is my code:

```
var counterContainer = document.querySelector(".website-counter");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
var visitCount = localStorage.getItem("page_view");

// Check if page_view entry is present
if (visitCount) {
  visitCount = Number(visitCount) + 1;
  localStorage.setItem("page_view", visitCount);
} else {
  visitCount = 1;
  localStorage.setItem("page_view", 1);
}
counterContainer.innerHTML = visitCount;

// Adding onClick event listener
resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  visitCount = 1;
  localStorage.setItem("page_view", 1);
  counterContainer.innerHTML = visitCount;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cookies instead of local storage.